# Window.open function opens in new tab in mac when the browser is maximized instead of new window

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I am trying to open a link in new window with window.open function in
mac its opening in new tab when the browser screen is maximized. But it opens in new window when the browser screen is not maximized.

So wanted to know If there is any way to make the browser open the link in new window when the browser window is maximized in mac.

Comment: Safari for Windows is a very old browser from a time, where pages are opened in new window and not in a new tab. Maybe there was a setting for this. On iPad and iPhone it opens a new TAB. And depending on the setting (open new tab in Background) it is just opened in the background or opens in foreground.  And actually your application cannot control, how a page is opened.

Comment: The issue with all the browsers in Mac machine